# Group by ID, each element of the new table is a vector

Tags: r, data.table

I have a table like this

```
data.table(ID = c(1,2,3,4,5,6), 
         R = c("s","s","n","n","s","s"), 
         S = c("a","a","a","b","b","b"))
```

and I'm trying to get this result

```
      a     b
s   1, 2      5, 6
n     3         4
```

Is there any option in data.table can do this?

Comment: I have 6 columns and 3 rows, but I think it doesn't really matter. I just want the ID of each different group.

Comment: `DT[, paste0(ID, collapse = ","), by = c("R","S")]` is a start, it doesn't give a vector, but a sting representation.

Comment: Just to extend @Chris idea `dcast(DT[, paste0(ID, collapse = ","), by = c("R","S")], R~S, value.var='V1')`

Comment: @Chris Consider to post that as a solution with the `dcast` option from `data.table`

Comment: @akrun I would, but OP is looking for a vector, not a string. Not sure if that is possible in data.table

Comment: @StevenBeaupré  It is basically Chris idea.  If he is not posting the solution, you can add it.

Comment: Thanks @Chris, akrun. This is what I want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `dcast` from `reshape2` with the appropriate aggregating function:

```
library(functional)
library(reshape2)

dcast(df, R~S, value.var='ID', fun.aggregate=Curry(paste0, collapse=','))
#  R   a   b
#1 n   3   4
#2 s 1,2 5,6
```

Or even short as @akrun underlined:

```
dcast(df, R~S, value.var='ID', toString)
```

Comment: functional is my base package :) very nice with `toString` !

Answer (score 5):

Here's an alternative that uses plain old data.table syntax:

```
DT[,lapply(split(ID,S),list),by=R]

# or...

DT[,lapply(split(ID,S),toString),by=R]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(R, S) %>% 
  summarise(i = toString(ID)) %>% 
  spread(S, i)
```

Which gives:

```
#Source: local data table [2 x 3]
#Groups: 
#
#  R    a    b
#1 n    3    4
#2 s 1, 2 5, 6
```

**Note:** This will store the result in a string. If you want a more convenient format to access the elements, you could store in a list:

```
df2 <- df %>% 
  group_by(R, S) %>% 
  summarise(i = list(ID)) %>% 
  spread(S, i)
```

Which gives:

```
#Source: local data table [2 x 3]
#Groups: 
#
#  R        a        b
#1 n <dbl[1]> <dbl[1]>
#2 s <dbl[2]> <dbl[2]>
```

You can then access the elements by doing:

```
> df2$a[[2]][2]
#[1] "2"
```