# Get the actual values in the category column in R

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I have a dataframe that looks like this

```
ID <- c('D101','D101','D102','D102','D101','D102') 
Number <- c(7,31,64,66,8,3) 
Category <- c('Set_A','Set_B','Set_C','Set_C','Set_A','Set_A')
df <- data.frame(ID,Number,Category)
df

    ID Number Category
1 D101      7    Set_A
2 D101     31    Set_B
3 D102     64    Set_C
4 D102     66    Set_C
5 D101      8    Set_A
6 D102      3    Set_A
```

Now I get the summary of the category

```
table(df$ID,df$Category)
```

which gives me,

```
       Set_A Set_B Set_C
  D101     2     1     0
  D102     1     0     2
```

My questions are

1) Why does the "ID"  disappear at the output?. Its just a blank. How can I get an output like this

```
   ID   Set_A Set_B Set_C
  D101     2     1     0
  D102     1     0     2
```

2) I want an output like the below that shows what numbers are for every ID. Please note that I would be applying this to a bigger dataset.

```
   ID   Set_A Set_B Set_C
  D101   7,8    31     0
  D102    31     0   64,66
```

Can we achieve something like this or may be similar in R? Please suggest alternatives. I highly appreciate your help.

Comment: see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31543508/group-id-in-r-data-table-each-element-of-the-new-table-is-a-vector?noredirect=1

Comment: Wonderful. Thank you so much for pointing that out.

Comment: how do I solve my question 1?

Comment: You can convert it to data.frame and create the ID column from the rownames (using your table) or as mentioned in the link, dcast like functions can be used. i.e. `dcast(df, ID~Category, value.var='Number', length)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `reshape2` library has the `dcast()` function, which is a bit like `table()`, but awesomer.

For part 1:

```
dcast(df, ID~Category, value.var='Number', fun.aggregate=length)

    ID Set_A Set_B Set_C
1 D101     2     1     0
2 D102     1     0     2
```

For part 2:

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(df, ID~Category, value.var='Number', fun.aggregate=paste0, collapse=',')

    ID Set_A Set_B Set_C
1 D101   7,8    31      
2 D102     3       64,66
```

Though I suspect this latter one will get unwieldy for larger datasets.

PS: The data.table version is always faster, although it feels a bit like black magic:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[,lapply(split(Number, Category), toString), by=ID]
```

Comment: For their first question you can add `tbl <- table(df$ID, df$Category);dcast(data.frame(tbl), Var1~Var2, value.var="Freq")`

Comment: @PierreLafortune  The more direct method would be `dcast(df, ID~Category, value.var='Number', length)`

Comment: @akrun is there a way to achieve the same with `aggregate`? I am trying that but I do not know why I can't obtain the same result.

Comment: @SabDeM  Using `aggregate`, you get the long form `aggregate(Number~ID+Category, df, length)`

Comment: @akrun I knot that, I meant the result with the `dcast` where elements are not frequencies but the values itself. Please post a base R answer, I am trying but still failing hahaha.

Comment: @SabDeM Sorry, I didn't get your comment.  Can you post the solution and we work on that :-)

Comment: @akrun actually I do not have a base R solution (just a mess with `aggregate`) that's why I am asking to you hahaha.

Comment: @SabDeM As I showed in `aggregate` it is just a long format output.  Or could you post that as a question so that I can better understand what you are after

Comment: @SabDeM It's in long form as mentioned, but it's `aggregate(Number~ID+Category, df, paste,collapse = ',')`

Comment: `data.table` also has (enhanced) `dcast` and `melt` functions. You don't need `reshape2` package at all.

Answer (score 1):

Base R and a drop in parallel hint for more performance:

```
# split into groups
dflist <- split(df$Number,list(df$ID,df$Category))

# counts
counts <- lapply(dflist,length)

# numbers per id
numbersperid <- lapply(dflist,paste,collapse = ',')

# speed up using
require(parallel)
parLapply()

# put into appropriate form
# probably better to parse element names but this seems to work
countsdf <- data.frame(matrix(counts,nrow = 2)) # 2 could probably be length(levels(df$ID))
names(countsdf) <- levels(df$Category)
countsdf$ID <- unique(df$ID)
```

An alternate way to put into appropriate form with tidyr (replaces last 3 lines above):

```
require(tidyr)
countsdf <- stack(counts)
countsdf <- separate(data = countsdf,col = ind,into = c('id','set'),sep = '\\.',)
spread(data = countsdf,set,values)
```